# 2 similar beans use same injected fields, in one the fields are null, the other are filled

Tags: java, dependency-injection, null, javabeans

I have 2 beans that are created in the same SecurityConfig class, like this:

```
@Bean
ApiClientRequestFactory getKeycloakClientRequestFactory() {
    println "Init keycloakClientRequestFactory "+customerContextProviderFactory

    ApiClientRequestFactory factory = new ApiClientRequestFactory(customerContextProviderFactory, tokenProvider)
    factory.setConnectionRequestTimeout(5000)
    factory.setReadTimeout(1200000)
    return factory
}

@Bean
KeycloakAsyncClientRequestFactory getKeycloakAsyncClientRequestFactory() {
    println "Init keycloakAsyncClientRequestFactory "+customerContextProviderFactory

    KeycloakAsyncClientRequestFactory factory = new KeycloakAsyncClientRequestFactory(customerContextProviderFactory, tokenProvider)
    factory.setConnectionRequestTimeout(20000)
    factory.setReadTimeout(1200000)
    return factory
}
```

The customerContextProviderFactory and tokenProviderare both @Autowired within the Security config class, these methods are like:

```
class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
GrailsApplication grailsApplication
@Autowired
CustomerContextProviderFactory customerContextProviderFactory
@Autowired
TokenProvider tokenProvider
```

Now, when i start my application, both of the fields are null in the first instance but filled in the second. I don't understand what the difference would be. Can someone help me figure it out? The console shows:

```
Init keycloakClientRequestFactory null

Init keycloakAsyncClientRequestFactory com.tst.myapp.customer.RoleBasedCustomerContextProviderFactory@22a4c764
```